# Closure operation in a uniform topology.

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

The closure operation in the uniform topology is $$\overline{A} = \bigcap_{E \in \mathcal{U}} E \cdot A$$ where $E \cdot A$ is the set of all $E$-left-relatives of $A$. I cannot seem to prove that $$\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$$ It is fairly straightforward to show that $\bar{A} \cup \bar{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$, but the reverse direction eludes me because I can't see how to get from $$(p \in E \cdot A \text{ or } p \in E \cdot B) \text{ for all } E \in \mathcal{U}$$ to $$(p \in E \cdot A \text{ for all } E \in \mathcal{U}) \text{ or } (p \in E \cdot B \text{ for all } E \in \mathcal{U})$$

Any tips?

Comment: I’ve not seen this terminology before. Do you mean that $$E\cdot A=\{p\in X:\exists a\in A(\langle x,a\rangle\in E\}\;?$$

Comment: Show $\overline{A\cup B}\setminus \overline{A} \subset \overline{B}$. If there is an $E$ with $p \notin E\cdot A$, then you must have $p \in \bigcap E\cdot B$.

Comment: Wait, why is that? If there is an $E$ with $p \not \in E \cdot A$, which implies that $p \in E \cdot B$, how does that imply that $p \in E \cdot B$ for EVERY $E \in \mathcal{U}$?

Comment: Obviously, if $E_1 \subset E_2$, then $E_1\cdot B \subset E_2\cdot B$. By assumption, we have $p \notin E_a\cdot A$. But for every $E$, we have $p \in E\cdot (A\cup B) = (E\cdot A) \cup (E\cdot B)$, so for $E \subset E_a$, that implies $p \in E\cdot B$. For $E \not\subset E_a$, we have $p\in (E\cap E_a)\cdot B \subset E\cdot B$.

Comment: Ahh I see. @Brian: yes. I am getting the notation from http://math.berkeley.edu/~wodzicki/H104.F13/UniformStructure.pdf